# Get number value from MySQL and make <select> countdown to zero

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How can I make in PHP dropdown menu which will have options from 0 to certain number which mysqlquery will retrieve?

I've tried while loop but it just retrieves one option with value of mysql. iex. in mysql table there is value six (6). So I want it to printed like this:

```
<select name="count">  
<option value="">Count</option>  
<option value="1">1</option>  
<option value="2">2</option>  
.  
.  
.  
<option value="6">6</option>  
</select>
```

So far its this:

```
$count = mysql_query('SELECT count FROM table') or die ('MySQL error! Error with query!');  
print('<select name="count">');  
print('<option="">Count</option>');  
while($values = mysql_fetch_array($count))  
{  
print('<option value="');  
print $values;  
print('">');  
print  $values;
print('</option>');  
}   
print('</select>');
```

Comment: Show us what you've done so far

Comment: Obviously you haven't tried very hard.  This is a very trivial example of a while or for loop.  Post all of your attempts and we can correct them for you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So this is not a place for simple questions? I'm tend to ask about things I don't either know or can't myself figure out an answer.

Comment: It's a place for any type of (programming) question, but people are much more willing to help when you show that you've made some effort of your own to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the number from your database - let us say it is stored in `$maxnum` - then run through all the values from `1` to `$maxnum`, using a `for` loop, echoing an `<option>` element in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.  First, you need to get the results of the MySQL query into a variable (see the `$result` line below).  Then, you need to fetch the first row (since you are only returning a single row) into an array.  Take the first element of that array to be your count value, then do a for loop against that to create the additional `option` elements.

```
<select name="count">  
    <option value="">Count</option>  
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT count(*) FROM table') or die ('MySQL error! Error with query!');
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $count = $row[0];

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name="mynolist" id="mynolist" onchange="form.submit()">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <10; $i++)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

do it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; this only creates a dropdown with 10 fixed elements, with no regard to even getting the information from the database.